# Take input from user while websocket server running

Tags: python, input, websocket, botnet

So, i need to make something like botnet but for educational purposes, just to demonstrate how botnet works, i need it for video, so i was trying to write my own but cant make work both websocket server for communication and take input from the user, the code just freezes on the websocket and wont continue to take input from user. Theres my code:

```html
from colorama import Fore, Style
import socket
import title
import os
import asyncio
import websockets
from aioconsole import ainput

connections = 0
started = False
started_lock = asyncio.Lock()

# ----------- TITLE ----------- #
print(title.generate_title())

# ----------- COMMANDS ----------- #
hostname = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

async def handler(websocket, path):
    global connections
    connections += 1

    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            pass
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        connections -= 1

async def start_websocket_server():
    global started

    try:
        async with started_lock:
            started = True
        start_server = await websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 5914)
        print(f"{Fore.BLUE}[*]: {Style.RESET_ALL}Websocket server started!")
        await start_server.wait_closed()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{Fore.RED}[ERR]: {Style.RESET_ALL}An error occurred while starting websocket server: {e}")

def clear():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        os.system('clear')

async def user_input():
    while True:
        if started:
            try:
                user_input = await ainput(f"{ip}:{hostname}> ")
                if user_input.strip() == "help":
                    print("""List of available commands:
                    connections - number of connected bots.
                    sessions - get all bots and ids
                    getinfo {id} - get info about bot by id
                    exit - exit the program""")
                elif user_input.strip() == "cls" or user_input.strip() == "clear":
                    clear()
                elif user_input.strip() == "connections":
                    print(f"{Fore.BLUE}[*]: {Style.RESET_ALL}There are currently connected {connections} bots.")
                elif user_input.strip() == "exit":
                    print("Exiting...")
                    return
                else:
                    print(f"Unknown command '{user_input}'\nView all commands using 'help'")
            except EOFError:
                print("EOFError. Exiting...")
                break
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("User interrupted. Exiting...")
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

async def main():
    print(f"{Fore.BLUE}[*]: {Style.RESET_ALL}Starting websocket server...")

    # Start WebSocket server
    await start_websocket_server()

    # Start user input
    await user_input()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

And theres the title library:

```html
from pyfiglet import Figlet
from colorama import Fore, Style
import random

title_fonts = ['cybermedium', 'rectangles', 'cyberlarge', '3-d', 'banner', 'banner3', 'banner4', 'chunky', 'colossal', 'computer', 'cosmic', 'crawford', 'cricket', 'doom', 'epic', 'poison']

try:
    import pyfiglet
except ImportError:
    import subprocess
    subprocess.run(['pip', 'install', 'pyfiglet'])
    import pyfiglet

# Generate and return the title with a random readable font
def generate_title():
    selected_font = random.choice(title_fonts)
    if selected_font == 'cosmic':
        fig = Figlet(font=selected_font, width=120)
        title = fig.renderText('Control Hub').strip()
    else:
        fig = Figlet(font=selected_font, width=100)
        title = fig.renderText('ControlHub').strip()
    return Fore.MAGENTA + title + f"\n" + Style.RESET_ALL
```

Tried adding multithreads and it helped, but not much cause I have to every time kill python via task manager cause it wont exit using KeyboardInterrupt